# How to export two constructors in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm very new to Angular and web development and currently trying to add a dark mode theme switcher to an existing application. For this I need to add a constructor to the export class of the  **app.component.ts**

The constructor that I need to add for the theme switcher looks like this:

```
export class AppComponent 
 implements OnInit{ constructor (private themeService: ThemeService, private renderer: Renderer2) {} 
     ngOnInit(): void {
        this.themeService.themeChanges().subscribe(theme => {
if (theme.oldValue) { 
this.renderer.removeClass(document.body, theme.oldValue); 
} 
this.renderer.addClass(document.body, theme.newValue); 
})
}
}
```

There is however an existing constructor already being exported in the app.compenent.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ipsum-dashboard-webclient';

  // Dont remove unused services from this constructor because they need to be initialized while app start up
  // If we add them to the constructor they are acting like a startup bean
  constructor(private store: Store<{}>, private push: PushService) {
    if (environment.mock && !environment.production) {
      console.warn('ipsum-dashboard-webclient -> You are running in MOCK Mode aka \'Lorem  Mode\'. Security is disabled and all http responses are mocked with dummy data.' +
        ' Check the  ./asset/mock folder to adjust you mockdata if necessary.');
    }
    this.store.dispatch(configRequest());
  }
```

***How do I correctly merge both of them together?***

Comment: It's either AngularJS or Angular - not both. Which version is it? Read the tag descriptions and update your question accordingly

Comment: Just add the parameters you need to add to the existing constructor.

Comment: Please be more precise.

Comment: Your first constructor is empty. It just has two parameters. Add those parameter declaration to your target constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to merge `constructor` parameters (we don't care of the order).
And add the content of a `constructor` inside the other :

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'ipsum-dashboard-webclient';

    constructor (
        private themeService: ThemeService,
        private renderer: Renderer2,
        private store: Store<{}>,
        private push: PushService
    ) {
        if (environment.mock && !environment.production) {
            console.warn('ipsum-dashboard-webclient -> You are running in MOCK Mode aka \'Lorem  Mode\'. Security is disabled and all http responses are mocked with dummy data.' +
        ' Check the  ./asset/mock folder to adjust you mockdata if necessary.');
        }
        this.store.dispatch(configRequest());
    } 

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.themeService.themeChanges().subscribe(theme => {
            if (theme.oldValue) { 
                this.renderer.removeClass(document.body, theme.oldValue); 
            }
            this.renderer.addClass(document.body, theme.newValue); 
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: My sincerest appreciation for your answer sir! It solved my problem perfectly and helped me understand the structure for future useses.